# Android 8 and Above: How to get List of open apps in app tray

Tags: android

How can I get the list of running/opened app that are in my "app tray".

I want to identify a particulate app and check it still running of killed by user or OS.

I tried all solution using ActivityManager  but non of them seems to be working for API 8+